# Porque esse componente criado com função não funciona?

Tags: react, react-native

Componente criando com função, retorna erro

```js
import { React } from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";

const Product = () => <Text>Product</Text>;

export default Product;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas quando é criado com classe ele funciona normalmente

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Text } from "react-native";

export default class Product extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <Text>Deu certo</Text>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No exemplo de função vc está importando o React com destructing e não como default

mudar de:

```
import { React } from "react";
```

para:

```
import React from "react";
```

Comment: Excelente observação.

Answer (score 0):

Quando você exporta um objeto, exemplo:

```
export {
  func1,
  func2
}
```

Ao importar você deve usar o [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Atribuicao_via_desestruturacao), nova feature do ES6 que tem como finalidade extrair propriedades de um objeto ou até mesmo valores de um array.

Uso para o exemplo acima: `import { func1, func2 } from './pathArquivo';`

Quando você export por *default* você não precisa usar o destructuring.

No exemplo do React o uso correto é:

```
import React from 'react'
```